# valor del <option value> se pierde al actualizar

Tags: php, pdo

amigos cuando trato de actualizar el valor del select no me muestra lo que había registrado anteriormente en el select porque la idea es que si ya registrarse un valor del select cuando haya una actualización debería mostrarte el valor que ya escogiste primero para luego seleccionar otro valor si fuese el caso.

```
<?php
$id_mis_cuentas= $_GET['id_mis_cuentas'];
$consulta = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT 
mis_cuentas.id_mis_cuentas,
mis_cuentas.id_bancos_admin,
mis_cuentas.id_cuentas_admin,
mis_cuentas.numero_cuenta_admin,
bancos.id_bancos, 
bancos.bancos,
cuentas.id_cuentas,
cuentas.cuentas
FROM mis_cuentas INNER JOIN bancos ON 
mis_cuentas.id_bancos_admin=bancos.id_bancos
INNER JOIN cuentas ON mis_cuentas.id_cuentas_admin=cuentas.id_cuentas WHERE 
id_mis_cuentas=:id_mis_cuentas");
 $consulta->execute(array(':id_mis_cuentas'=>$id_mis_cuentas));
 $editar_linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);{
 extract($editar_linea);
 ?>
 <form class="col s12 m12 l12" action="actualizarmiscuentas" name="frmContacto" method="GET">

  <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
  <select name="id_cuentas" id="id_cuentas" class="browser-default" required/>
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Tipo de Cuenta:</option>
  <?php
   $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM cuentas ORDER BY id_cuentas");
   while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
   <option <?php if($editar_linea['id_cuentas'] == $linea['cuentas']){ ?> selected <?php }?> value="<?= $linea['id_cuentas'] ;?>">
   <?php echo $linea['cuentas'] ;?></option>
  <?php
     }
     ?>
     </select>
     </div>

   <input type='hidden' name='id_mis_cuentas' value='<?php echo $id_mis_cuentas; ?>'>
   </form>
   <?php

    }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas haciendo mal la comparacion del selected pues en `$linea` comparas con `cuentas` y no con `id_cuentas`.

Cambialo a esto y mira si funciona.

```
 <option <?php if($editar_linea['id_cuentas'] == $linea['id_cuentas']){ ?> selected <?php }?> value="<?= $linea['id_cuentas'] ;?>">
```

Comment: eso era gracias.